# Hash function for two integer arrays with minimal collisions

Tags: java, arrays, hash, computation-theory, hash-function

I'm working on a problem where I want to store objects consisting of two integer arrays of equal length (e.g. int `a[] ={1,2,3,4}` and int `b[] ={1,2,2,6}`) in a data structure (e.g. hashmap) . However, for different objects, the length of the two arrays can vary. Both arrays are consisting of integers from a given interval (e.g. between 0-200).

For storing the objects with the two arrays, I want to assign a single hashkey that is fast to compute, preserves both sequences, and will lead to minimal collisions.

I have first tried using `Arrays.deepHashCode(int[][])` but quickly found collisions. Second, I tried to distribute the values in the arrays more equally, by changing a[i] and b[i] to new values so that `a_new[i] = Math.pow(31,a[i]) % Math.pow(2,16)` (actually using BigInteger to avoid overflow: `BigInteger.valueOf(31).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(a[i]), BigInteger.valueOf(Math.pow(2,16)))`; using BigInteger. Since the interval of values is limited I can pre-calculate it for each possible value. As a result I came up with following solution:

```
    int result = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result = result * 31 * a_new[i];
        result = result * 31 * b_new[i];
    }
```

This solution seems to work when there are only smaller arrays, but once a[] and b[] can contain up to 10 values it also leads to collisions. Now I wonder, if there is a better way to achieve what i want with less collisions.

Edit: I fixed it to use a proper java code for the powers

Comment: That's not real Java.  There is no "mod" operator in Java, and ... it is unclear what you mean by `^`.  Do you mean exponentiation or bitwise OR?  Show us the code you are actually using.

Comment: @stephen C: I suppose it symbolizes the "power of" ^ instead of double asterisks. If so the result int is overflowed. Long should be used instead of int(eger)

Comment: @StephenC: I fixed the code to use actual java code. Yes I was using "power of" in combination with BigInteger to handle the modulo of the large power of results.

Comment: Can you clarify what types of objects you consider equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses and ideas. Eventually, I came up with a different solution that seems to work for me and has so far not led to any collisions.

Instead of creating a single hash for both arrays, I decided to create two different hashes. One hash is based on the set of integers in the arrays and the other one is based on the sequences (same as in my question). Both hashes are then used as keys in a MultiKeyMap (Apache Commons Collections 4.4 API), where I store the data connected to the two arrays.

Sequence-based hash:

```
    int result = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result = result * 31 * a_new[i];
        result = result * 31 * b_new[i];
    }

    return result;
```

Set-based hash:

```
    int resultA = 31;
    int resultB = 179;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        resultA += a_new[i];
        resultB += b_new[i];
    }

   return resultA *31 * resultB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of multiplying each `a[i]` and `b[i]` by 31, you could store an array of primes, and the current number in the array by `prime[i]`?

Something like this:

```
int result = 31;
int[] primes = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ... };
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result = result * primes[i % primes.length] * a_new[i]
        result = result * primes[i % primes.length] * b_new[i]
    }
```

You can also try with larger primes to make collisions less likely.

Comment: I really like that idea and tried it with different primes in the array (e.g. starting at 31) and using both the modified values and original values of my arrays. Although performing better than Objects.hash it unfortunately also led to collisions after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Just stating the obvious...

```
return Objects.hash(a_new, b_new);
```